# Ansible: can't set vars variable

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to build a playbook that collects certain information from my hosts.
So I'll just fire-up some shell commands and store their return values in a variable. Each command output (e.g. 'ls -la') shall be concaternated to the former so if all hosts were passed I'll get a complete list.

So this is my playbook:

```
---
- name: try to set variable
  hosts: all

  vars:
    my_test_var: []

  tasks:

    - name: just get a simple list and show it
      shell: ls -la
      register: out
      my_test_var: "{{ my_test_var + out.stdout }}"

    - debug:
      msg: "Listing of current dir: {{ my_test_var }}"
```

So first I create an empty list called: "my_test_var" and the first task should append its output from the "ls -la" command.

But it doesn't. 
Ansible just ignores the variable. But why ?!

```
[WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: my_test_var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few issues with your playbook.

1:

```
- debug:
  msg: "Listing of current dir: {{ my_test_var }}"
```

`msg` needs one more indentation, you need to change to:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Listing of current dir: {{ my_test_var }}"
```

2:

you cant get the output from ls -al and in the same task manipulate the my_test_var. you need to use seperate tasks. PLease see my playbook below about this.

3:

the `out.stdout` variable is a string variable, while the `my_test_var` is a list. if you want to add the whole `out.stdout` to the list, you need to use this syntax:

```
my_test_var: "{{ my_test_var + [ out.stdout ] }}"
```

if your intention was to add the `out.stdout_lines` (which is a list of each line of the ls -al output), your syntax is fine:

```
my_test_var: "{{ my_test_var + out.stdout_lines }}"
```

tip:

you dont need to "initialize" the `my_test_var` variable to an empty list. you can use the `default` filter by using:

```
my_test_var: "{{ my_test_var|default([]) + out.stdout_lines }}"
```

full playbook below:

```
---
- name: try to set variable
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # my_test_var: []

  tasks:

    - name: just get a simple list and show it
      shell: ls -la
      register: out

    - name: print out
      debug:
        var: out

    - name: set the my_test_var to the output
      set_fact:
        my_test_var: "{{ my_test_var|default([]) + out.stdout_lines }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_test_var
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. Just one thing: If I'd have more than one task that produces some output I'd like to add to "my_test_var" AFAIK I can't use "set_fact" as you can't overwrite it once it's set (?)

Comment: you can use this syntax to append more elements in the `my_test_var` list: `my_test_var: "{{ my_test_var|default([]) + <the new items you want to add> }}"`